# Probability - Disjoint subsets

Tags: probability

> Suppose that events A and B are disjoint.  Under what conditions are A' and B' disjoint?

If A and B are disjoint, then the sets A and B have no elements in common but they are in the sample space S.  Therefore A' and B' would never be disjoint unless they were in a different sample space S.

Is this correct or am I way off in the left field?  When it says A' and B' are disjoint, I know it means $A' \cap B'=0$.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Do you know De Morgan's laws?

Comment: $(A \cup B)' = A' \cap B'$.  So the condition is that $(A \cup B)' =0$.  Is that it? @DanielFischer

Comment: Right. Now, what is another way to say $(A \cup B)' = \varnothing$?

Comment: $1- (A \cup B) = 0$ $\therefore (A \cup B) =1$.  But what does this mean? A and B are disjoint... *confused* @DanielFischer

Comment: If by $1$ you mean $S$ (and $\varnothing$ by $0$), then yes.

Comment: But what does this mean in English?  This just means that the union of A and B must be in the same sample space right? How is this very enlightening?  A and B are disjoint.  This doesn't really explain why A' and B' must be disjoint... does it?

Comment: The complement of $A \cup B$ being empty means the union $A \cup B$ is the entire sample space. So if we have $A \cap B = \varnothing$, then the complements are disjoint if and only if the union is the entire space, and that means $B$ is the complement of $A$.

Comment: Oh Thank you so much @DanielFischer!.  I wouldn't have been able to get to the last step B=A'.